# How can I show a PDF file in a browser from my database?

Tags: php

I want to show a PDF file in the browser from the database using embed tag of HTML. How can I do this? Here is my PHP Code:

```
$content_query="select * from time_table where semester_no=$current_semester";
$apply_query=sqlsrv_query($conn,$content_query);
$result_content = sqlsrv_fetch_array($apply_query);

$file_directory=$result_content['file_path'];
$exists=file_exists($result_content['file_path']);
$ext=$result_content['name']; 

echo $direc="../admin/pages/".$file_directory; exit;
$path=$direc.$file_directory;
```

Comment: add the code you tried along with the error faced

Comment: You are printing the **path** of the file, not its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this to your html code, (this assumes your pdf is stored in a publicly accessible path)

```
<embed src="{{url_to_pdf}}" width="1920" height="1080"/>
```

Or optionally you could also use this,

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url={{url_to_pdf}}" width="1920" height="1080">
```